# Firebase database section listview

Tags: listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to retrieve data from Firebase  (section list adapter firebase database).
such as Firebase database.

[image: firebase database]

[image: table league activity]

Comment: .... and what have your tried so far? Can you post your code? Also, please remove the Firebase image and replace it with text so it can be used in an answer. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

i use this adapter

```
public class MatcmobikraAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MatchmobikooraModel> {

private static final String TAG = "MatchAdapter";

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private int  mLayoutResource;
private Context mContext;
private Typeface myTypeface;

public MatcmobikraAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<MatchmobikooraModel> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mLayoutResource = resource;
    this.mContext = context;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView team1logo, team2logo;       
    TextView team1, team2, matchtime;
    MatchmobikooraModel matchmobikooraModel;

}
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mLayoutResource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.matchtime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_time);
        holder.team1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.homescore);
        holder.team2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.awayscore);
        holder.team1logo  = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.homeicon);
        holder.team2logo  = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.awayicon);
        holder.matchmobikooraModel = getItem(position);
        myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "bein.ttf");
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

       // MatchmobikooraModel matchmobikooraModel = getItem(position);//Modelmatch modelmatch = getItem(position);



        holder.team1.setText(getItem(position).getTeam1());
        holder.team1.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        holder.team2.setText(getItem(position).getTeam2());
        holder.team2.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        holder.matchtime.setText(getItem(position).getMatch_time());
        holder.matchtime.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        PicassoClient.downloadimg(mContext, getItem(position).getTeam1logo(), holder.team1logo);
        PicassoClient.downloadimg(mContext, getItem(position).getTeam2logo(), holder.team2logo);

  return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

and this code to retrieve data frome firebase

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "Match Fragment";

private ListView mListView;
private ArrayList<MatchmobikooraModel> mMatchmobikooraModels;
private MatcmobikraAdapter matcmobikraAdapter;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);

    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listMatch3);

    mMatchmobikooraModels = new ArrayList<>();



    getmobara();
    return view;
}

private void getmobara(){
    DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("match").child("leagues");
    Query query = myRef;

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2 = dataSnapshot1.child("league_matches");

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot3 : dataSnapshot2.getChildren()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "found mobara time : " +dataSnapshot3.child("match_time").getValue());

                    MatchmobikooraModel matchmobikooraModel = new MatchmobikooraModel();

                    Map<String, Object> objectMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot3.getValue();

                    Log.d(TAG, "found match time : " + dataSnapshot3.child("match_time").getValue());

                            // matchmobikooraModel.setMatch_id(objectMap.get("match_id").toString());
                    matchmobikooraModel.setMatch_time(objectMap.get("match_time").toString());
                    matchmobikooraModel.setTeam1(objectMap.get("team1").toString());
                    matchmobikooraModel.setTeam1logo(objectMap.get("team1logo").toString());
                    matchmobikooraModel.setTeam2(objectMap.get("team2").toString());
                    matchmobikooraModel.setTeam2logo(objectMap.get("team2logo").toString());
                    mMatchmobikooraModels.add(matchmobikooraModel);

                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: get match count " + mMatchmobikooraModels.size());
                matcmobikraAdapter = new MatcmobikraAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_game_logos, mMatchmobikooraModels);
                mListView.setAdapter(matcmobikraAdapter);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MeetingShow extends AppCompatActivity {

  ListView listView;
  List<MeetingInfo> list;
  ProgressDialog progressDialog;
  private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
  MeetingAdapter eventAdapter;

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_meeting_show);

    listView=findViewById(R.id.meetinglistview);


    list=new ArrayList<>();
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Fetching.... ");
    progressDialog.show();

// change according to your node detail
    databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Meeting");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        MeetingInfo imageinfo=dataSnapshot.getValue(MeetingInfo.class);
        list.clear();
        for(DataSnapshot snapshot :dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
          MeetingInfo imageInfo=snapshot.getValue(MeetingInfo.class);
          imageInfo.setMeetingkey(snapshot.getKey());
          list.add(imageInfo);
        }
        eventAdapter =new MeetingAdapter(MeetingShow.this,R.layout.activity_meeting_format,list);
        listView.setAdapter(eventAdapter);
      }

      @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(MeetingShow.this, databaseError.getCode(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }
    });
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int i, long l) {
       // progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(MeetingShow.this);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);


        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MeetingShow.this);

        alert.setTitle("Delete entry");
        alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?");
        alert.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//delete entry by clicking on listview item
            final MeetingInfo meetingInfo=list.get(i);
            final String selecteditem=meetingInfo.getMeetingkey();
            databaseReference.child(selecteditem).removeValue();
            Toast.makeText(MeetingShow.this,"Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            listView.setAdapter(eventAdapter);


          }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);   }
        });
        alert.show();
      }        });
      }
      }
```